# Question about pausing an if statement through a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, coroutine

I've just started learning how to program in Unity. Have been trying to do some code every day for the last two-three weeks. I've gotten a bit stuck on a simple script. This script is as follows:

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    public float timeWaited = 0.5f;


    public void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // On spacebar press, send dog
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        { 
            StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
        }
        

    }
    private IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
    {
        Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        Debug.Log("Waited 0.5 seconds!");
        
       
    }
} `
```

I want there to be a 0.5 second break in between spacebar presses (Which would spawn a dog). I assume this doesn't work because the coroutine just plays from the start when pressing spacebar. However, I can't think of a way to fix this. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your code is starting a new coroutine every time spacebar is pressed. Even though you're technically waiting within *each coroutine instance* for 1 second (even though you're logging 0.5 seconds, your code waits for 1 second, not 0.5), it does not prevent a new coroutine from starting. So, you're almost correct - coroutine restarts from the top - a *new instance of it* - not the same one. You can instead just keep some sort of a `TimeSpan` variable to keep track of time between keypresses, and eliminate the coroutine altogether.

Comment: Also, the `if (Time.time >= timeWaited)` statement is always `true` after first few frames - it returns the *total amount of seconds since the game started*. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html   Consider using `Time.deltaTime` instead, and accumulate it into some variable to figure out if it's time to spawn the next item (a dog in your case). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Comment: @CoolBots I'll see if I can make that work. Out of interest, is there any possible way a coroutine would work here though? Also I forgot to remove that line lol, was experimenting. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can make a coroutine work for this purpose. Suppose that you wanted to do some time-consuming task (say, the dog spawns with an animation that takes approx. half a second, which would be a good reason for the delay in between the spawns) - you can still start the coroutine as you do now, but I'd keep the main code responsible for checking whether or not it's time to start a new coroutine. Alternatively, you can run the coroutine "forever", and check keypresses within that coroutine, but that's not a typical use case for Unity coroutines.

Comment: @CoolBots `Time.deltaTime` is a totally different thing. He needs to wait for 0.5 seconds in-real time while `Time.deltaTime` returns only the time in seconds since the last frame. If somehow the time since the last frame it's smaller than 0.5 seconds, the coroutine will never trigger.

Comment: @MarcelAlexandru that's why I said *accumulate it into some variable*. This is a standard approach in game engines, btw - declare `float elapsedTime`, class-level (global variable in the script in Unity); each frame, *add the value of `Time.deltaTime` to that variable*, and check if it reached your desired time interval. If it has, reset it to zero and run the desired code.

Comment: @CoolBots There's no way to use that to do a colldown time, if you find a way you could share it with me and prove me wrong. You can't accumulate it since the value returned by it depends on how powerful the machine is, and how fast it works. So for example for X deltaTime could be 0.40 but for Y could be 0.80. This will mean that X could possibly spawn the object faster than Y does. Also, in some places or some parts of the game deltaTime can be lower, or higher depending on the frame rate the player gets. Also if he sums deltaTime the object won't be spawned anymore after some times.

Comment: And that's because if the time since the last frame it's 0.4s it will never reach let's say 0.9s (0.4 + 0.5 the colldown timer)

Comment: @MarcelAlexandru again, this is *standard approach* - not only is it possible, *it's how it's typically done*. I will add an answer to this question shortly, per your request.

Comment: @CoolBots Also notice there's also Time.realtimeSinceStartup which you are confusing with Time.time. While Time.time is returned at the beginning of each frame, Time.realtimeSinceStartup it's called every second as reported by the system timer. Time.time increases at the start of each frame, and Time.realtimeSinceStartup increases every real second. Time.time also pauses when the timescale is set to 0 and the game is paused. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html

Comment: @MarcelAlexandru per documentation of `Time.time`, line 1, under **Description**: The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only). **This is the time in seconds since the start of the game.** (emphasis mine). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html.   Per the link you posted of the documentation of `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`, Description: **In almost all cases you can and should use Time.time instead.**   I'm not confusing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is starting a new coroutine every time spacebar is pressed. Even though you're technically waiting within each coroutine instance for 0.5 seconds, it does not prevent a new coroutine from starting. So, you're almost correct - coroutine restarts from the top - a new instance of it - not the same one. Also, the statement `if (Time.time >= timeWaited)` is always `true` after first few frames - it returns the *total amount of seconds since the game started.* (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

Instead, let's use a *standard approach* to solve this problem - an *accumulator value*, that is incremented by `Time.deltaTime` each frame. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

#### Step 0: Define time to wait

You already have this in your code - it's called `timeWaited`. I will rename it here, for clarity. This value should be global to the script (in Unity terms) - this a *class field* in your  *MonoBehaviour*-derived class:

```cs
float minimumTimeBetweenDogSpawns = 0.5f;
```

#### Step 1: Accumulator variable

You don't have this variable in your code, so I am introducing it here. This value should be global to the script (in Unity terms) - this a *class field* in your  *MonoBehaviour*-derived class:

```cs
float elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed = 0;  // feel free to make the name shorter, lol!
```

#### Step 2: Accumulate `Time.deltaTime` on each frame

Now, the Unity Game Engine (in fact, all game engines) keeps track of time that elapsed between each frame. This is a very important concept in game development, as it allows smooth movements of objects regardless of a frame taking a little bit longer or little bit shorter to run - since we know the elapsed time since last frame, we can use it in calculating object positions, how much a unit should advance by, etc. In our case, we are just using this value to get to a desired point - 0.5 seconds in your case, expressed by the `minimumTimeBetweenDogSpawns` variable.

So, how and where do we accumulate the elapsed time? Simple - just add it in `Update`:

```cs
void Update()
{
   elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

#### Step 3: Check if it's time to spawn a new dog!

So, what do we do with this `elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed`? So far, it keeps growing... we need to check if it reached the value of interest - in our case, `minimumTimeBetweenDogSpawns` has been reached., but only if spacebar was pressed. Let's add an `if` statement in `Update` to do that. I'll expand on `Update` from Step 2:

```cs
void Update()
{
   elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed += Time.deltaTime;

   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) 
      && elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed >= minimumTimeBetweenDogSpawns)
   {
      // Do stuff! Spawn a dog! Run a coroutine! Have a ball!
    
      elapsedTimeSinceSpacebarLastPressed = 0;   // ...but don't forget to reset the accumulator!
   }
}
```

Did you catch that last line? Very important - **reset the accumulator!** This restarts the process, allowing us to spawn more dogs, but not before reaching the value specified by `minimumTimeBetweenDogSpawns`.

#### Notes

- Technically the coroutine is not necessary, but can be useful - suppose that you wanted to do some time-consuming task - say, the dog spawns with an animation that takes approx. half a second, which would be a good reason for the delay in-between the spawns.
- Contrary to some of the comments on the original post, *the difference between machines in terms of speed **does not matter** for this approach*! Time is time - all that might change between machines is *how many frames run before the next spawn* - but not the time elapsed! In a properly written game, we never care how many frames past - we rely on timing, which is why some version of `deltaTime` is provided by *every game engine and framework out there*.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Only thing I would change is to not make your own accumulator as one is already provided with ```Time.time```.  Instead, track an ```AvailableAfterTime```.  eg, ```if (ShouldSpawn && Time.time >= AvailableAfterTime ) { AvailableAfterTime = Time.time + Delay;  /* Do Work */ }```

Comment: @Immersive While that's workable, `Time.time` eventually gets *pretty big*, as it tracks time since start of game. It's also not resettable. Making our own accumulator (which is basically just a `float` - so no real overhead there) allows easy resetting, and easy tracking of *multiple "timers"* - we can declare several accumulators that are timing different actions (such as a shield recharge period timer, an enemy spawn timer, etc) - which are individually resettable, and *easily debuggable*, as each timer will only count up to their respective target value.

Comment: The big numbers thing is a fair argument, but the rest is just fluff as all timers are just variable stores for the timestamps/accumulators.  At the end of the day, you can have count-up, count-down or timestamps.  I use timestamps as it saves on per-frame writes.

Comment: @Immersive yeah, there are a number of ways to approach this. I've used multiple engines / frameworks (SFML, MonoGame), so I prefer approaches that are portable. `deltaTime` exists in all engines/frameworks in some variation, so the approach I described in my answer works well in any framework. I initially just commented on OP's problem, but got into a discussion with a user that suggested my approach isn't workable, requesting an explanation of how it would work - hence I wrote this answer.

Comment: portability is also a _great_ reason.  I often forget how comfortable Unity makes things where others don't always have those features.  All good. =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `Time.time` works like that, first of all. The [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) reads:

> The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only). This is the time in seconds since the start of the game.

> Time.time is the amount of time in seconds that the application has been running for. It is read-only.

The if statement in the coroutine is checking `Time.time`, and so it will always be above 0.5 and the dog will always be spawned.

Although a rather low-tech way of doing it, to fix the problem I would set a variable at the start and end of the coroutine, that way you can check another if statement against this variable. It also means that you could put this check next to the `Input.GetKeyDown()` check, and not have several coroutines running at once.

This would mean that the body of your script would look something like this:

```cs
public GameObject dogPrefab;
bool Waiting = false;

void Update() 
{
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !Waiting)
     {
         StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
     } else
     {
         Debug.Log("Waiting");
     }
}

IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    Waiting = true;

    Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    Debug.Log("Waited 0.5 seconds!");

    Waiting = false;
}
```

*(CoolBots already said most of this in the comments, but I can't comment so I just wanted to put this in anyway. I also have a bad habit of using a lot of coroutines, so as they said it's probably not necessary, but I personally would do it this way.)*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a coroutine to do this. You can simply use your `timeWaited` variable and every time you press the button you spawn the dog and sum the variable with the passed time since the beginning of the game and your wait time.

Something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dogPrefab;
    public float timeWaited = 0.5f;


    public void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // On spacebar press, send dog
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time >= timeWaited)
        { 
            SpawnDog();
            timeWaited = Time.time + timeWaited;
        }
        

    }
    private void SpawnDog()
    {
       
         Instantiate(dogPrefab, transform.position, dogPrefab.transform.rotation);
        Debug.Log("Waited 0.5 seconds!");
       
    }
} `
```